# Swift: Class parameter as default function parameter

Tags: core-data, swift, optional-parameters, class-variables

I'm trying to define a default function parameter in Swift. By default a reference within this class should be used (function `loadMyEntities(...)`). Xcode (v6 Beta 4) displays `Use of unresolved Identifier 'self'`. Using only `context`, instead of `self.context` causes the error `'DB.Type' does not have a member named 'context'`. How can I handle this, to use "values behind references" as default parameters.

In my specific case, core data should load entities in an extra created NSManagedObjectContext or in a default context otherwise.

```
class DB {
  var appDelegate: AppDelegate
  var context: NSManagedObjectContext
  var persistenceCoordinater: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

  init() {
    self.appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    self.context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    self.persistenceCoordinater = context.persistentStoreCoordinator
  }

  // !!! Here's the point where I want to use the DB objects context as default !!!
  func loadMyEntities(context: NSManagedObjectContext = self.context) -> [MyEntity] {
    // loading entities
  }

  // This function can be used 
  func createContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    var newContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    newContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistenceCoordinater
    return newContext
  }
}
```

A workaround would be defining the function twice, once with the parameter, once without, and delegate from the one without a given context.

```
func loadMyEntities() -> [MyEntity] {
  return loadMyEntities(self.context)
}

func loadMyEntities(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [MyEntity] {
    // loading entities
}
```

But that's not pretty nice ;-)

My question targets on parameter usage if swift, but comments for encapsulating core data in this way are also welcome.

Comment: why have you not use the final version of the Xcode6 instead of the old beta4?

Comment: had downloaded the newest verison before starting my new project. Tried version 6A317 now, same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that's not pretty nice ;-)

There's nothing wrong with the overloading approach. It's very clear and flexible. That's what overloads are for. I've encountered this numerous times so far, and keep being reminded that over-complicated defaults are the wrong solution. Swift has overloads for a reason. They solve exactly the problem here.

Remember, default parameters are just a shortcut for expressing an overload. There are limits on how far you can push a shortcut.

---

EDIT: In this particular case, the natural solution would be to convert the parameter to an optional (which is exactly what you mean; it's optional).

```
func loadMyEntities(context: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil) -> [MyEntity] {
    if let context = context ?? self.context {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree absolutely.
Maybe I'm motivated by the respect of purging the programming effort of implementing every function twice and the amount of displayed functions in the autocompletion list.

Comment: (guessing that the above if-let-?? will compile. Something very similar should.)

Comment: Works with empty curly brackets. Even if not the solution, it's a less expensive workaround, than overloading.