How to provide a default argument for a view builder that uses other parameter
In SwiftUI, I've run into the scenario where I'm creating a generic view, and I'd like one of the initializer's parameters to have a default value of another view. The catch is that this default value needs to use another parameter that the initializer has. For example:
struct GenericView<Content: View> {
    private let someArg: Arg
    private let content: Content

    init(
        someArg: Arg, 
        @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content = { DefaultView(arg: someArg) }
    ) { ... }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }

}

Now, obviously this doesn't work because I can't use the argument someArg as part of the default value for another parameter. The goal here is to be able to use GenericView without providing that view builder (for convenience, as it defaults to DefaultView), but also to have the flexibility to provide a custom view if needed.
That being said, what is the proper way to configure such a need? I know I can have two separate initializers and have one just not take in a content argument and have the other use a where clause, for example:
init(someArg: Arg) where Content == DefaultView { ... }

init(
    someArg: Arg,
    @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content
) {
    ...
}

this works; but, if I add additional properties that I also want to be optional/default to some view (just like content) then the number of initializers I'd need significantly increases, so it's not sustainable.

SwiftUI itself uses separate initialisers, so I doubt there is a better way at the moment. Just look at how many initialisers Text/TextField/Button has.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75756986/5133585

Whilst you will need separate initialisers, you can use extensions to help organise them and reduce the boilerplate.
extension GenericView where Content == DefaultView { 
    init(someArg: Arg, someArg2: Arg2) { ... }

    init(someArg: Arg) { 
        self.init(someArg: someArg, someArg2: Arg2())
    }
}

extension GenericView { 
    init(someArg: Arg, someArg2: Arg2, @ViewBuidler content: () -> Content) { ... }

    init(someArg: Arg, @ViewBuidler content: () -> Content) { 
        self.init(someArg: someArg, someArg2: Arg2(), content: content)
    }

}

